# The JWT is not available in the response Authorization header, but present in the Network tab

Tags: reactjs, cors

I have a Spring Boot app as a back-end API and a React app as a front end.
`CORS` is enabled in the Spring Boot and I use axios to send requests to the Spring Boot API.
When calling '/login', Spring Boot security kicks in and produces a JWT
token, which is passed back to ReactJS as the Authorization header. The
issue is that this header does not appear in the response received in the
React app `then` processing block. It does show correctly in the Developer
Tools Network tab. Below is the relevant code:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", LoginRequest)
  .then(response => {console.log("RRR ", response)});
```

The console output is as follows:

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data: "{"username":"test@test.com","password":"test$2"}"
headers:
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
__proto__: Object
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: {0: ƒ}
transformResponse: {0: ƒ}
url: "http://localhost:8080/login"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
data: ""
headers: {pragma: "no-cache", cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", expires: "0"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you copy-paste the console log?

Comment: This is what shows on the Network tab:Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ1ODk0ODQxfQ.sROTYArLRh0Uzq9lczfdOuKGBm9lkay2qlHKSxqm4GQOS8GtotSGhswuyK5TFgGNh5GvacBI9c_W8MG6gzsIjw
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 16 Dec 2018 21:14:01 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers

Comment: you should be able to print the headers from the response in axios from `response.headers`. It might be there is a axio interceptors or an exception you are not catching. I would be good to see what you get in the output of the console

Comment: Yes, I printed. The Authorization is not there. I am not allowed to include screen shots. This is what I got: {pragma: "no-cache", cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", expires: "0"}
cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
expires: "0"
pragma: "no-cache"

Comment: You need to ensure the Spring Boot API server returns the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with a value that includes 'Authorization'.

Comment: Added the header and it worked! Thank you very much!